# Increasing Session Timeout in ASP vNext RC1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I noticed the session timed out now is around 20-30 minutes .

This is the code I used before, but it's not working on RC1 .

```
app.UseInMemorySession(configure: s => s.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
```

I also want to preserve the session state even if the IIS website process restarts... so I guess UseInMemorySession is not the best option .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Startup.cs` there should be a `ConfigureServices` method, you increase the `IdleTimeout` within there:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Code omitted        
    services.AddSession(options => { 
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50); 
            options.CookieName = ".FooApplication";
        });
}
```

You can use Redis or SqlServerCaching, I have never done so as I avoid using session in favour of OAuth and Claims that are serialized within a token on the client.

This article looks like it could be what you would need:

[Using Sessions and HttpContext in ASP.NET 5 and MVC6](http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/#use-a-redis-or-sql-server-cache-instead)

Comment: It worked but I didn't manage to find this nuget package to use Redis cache: "Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Redis"

Comment: @FAndrei Nice one. :) I think it could be this `"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis": "1.0.0-rc1-final"`. This looks a good article on it http://www.hossambarakat.net/2016/02/03/configuring-redis-as-asp-net-core-1-0-session-store/